# How to get dir="rtl" to work with bootstrap 4.3.1?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, right-to-left

I am creating a simple html/css page using bootstrap 4.3.1 . In one paragraph, I will be using some arabic text which needs to show up in a right-to-left format.

I have tried to use `direction:rtl` in `css` , `dir="rtl"` in `html` and `bidi-override` as well. But nothing seems to be working. I think it has got something to do with bootstrap 4.3.1 but I could be wrong. I am unable to understand where I am going wrong and would greatly appreciate any help.

This is my html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid black">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ayat_box">
        <div class="ayat_ar">
          <p class="ayat_ar_txt">
            حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ أَمْرُنَا وَفَارَ التَّنُّورُ قُلْنَا احْمِلْ فِيهَا مِنْ كُلٍّ زَوْجَيْنِ اثْنَيْنِ وَأَهْلَكَ إِلَّا مَنْ سَبَقَ عَلَيْهِ الْقَوْلُ وَمَنْ آَمَنَ وَمَا آَمَنَ مَعَهُ إِلَّا قَلِيلٌ  <span class="ayat_period">٣</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ayat_en">
          <p class="ayat_en_txt">
some content in ltr
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ayat_exp">
          <p class="ayat_exp_p">
some content in ltr
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ayat_box" style="background: pink">
        This is another box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.ayat_box
{
    width: 700px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.ayat_ar
{
    background: pink;
}

.ayat_ar_txt
{
    direction:rtl;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size:25px;
}

.ayat_period
{
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: AryaBootstrap is a bootstrap with dual layout align support and, used for LTR and RTL web design. Based on Bootstrap Ver 4.4.1, download from github, nuget and http://abs.aryavandidad.com/

Answer (score 12):

Just add `text-right` to align text right and `dir="rtl"` to make the right-to-left direction:

```html
          <p class="ayat_ar_txt text-right" dir="rtl">
            حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ أَمْرُنَا وَفَارَ التَّنُّورُ قُلْنَا احْمِلْ فِيهَا مِنْ كُلٍّ زَوْجَيْنِ اثْنَيْنِ وَأَهْلَكَ إِلَّا مَنْ سَبَقَ عَلَيْهِ الْقَوْلُ وَمَنْ آَمَنَ وَمَا آَمَنَ مَعَهُ إِلَّا قَلِيلٌ  <span class="ayat_period">٣</span>
          </p>
```

update: according to some replies:

You can do it without boot strap just like following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RTL Text Example</title>
    <style>
        .rtl {
            direction: rtl;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rtl">
        <p>مرحبا بالعالم!</p>
        <p>أهلا وسهلا بكم في موقعنا.</p>
        <p>شكرا جزيلا لزيارتكم.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother, you made my day!

Comment: The dir apply only for the body tag (at least in my code)

Comment: The dir global attribute is an enumerated attribute that indicates the directionality of the element's text:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with another library: **[RTL Bootstrap](http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/)**. It provides CSS to do the job.

This [git-diff](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/compare/main...RTLCSS:v4.2.1-rtl) is displaying you difference between the original Bootstrap library and the RTL Bootstrap library.

Comment: This seems to complicate things further for me as I have already done a lot of work on the website and changing my bootstrap version to one compatible with this library is breaking my website.

Comment: Take a better look at the second link, I provided. You could see there is only a few updates on the scss. You could analyze it and some changes to you own css addon.

Comment: I used the second link proposed by @AlexandreTranchant and **it works beautifully!!** Thank you.

Comment: @ShahQuadri: Using the RTL version of Bootstrap in Vue is simple as changing the import line. After installing the RTL Bootstrap, just use import 'bootstrap-v4-rtl/dist/css/bootstrap.css'. That is it! all things magically goes RTL

Answer (score 4):

you can add these classes to your bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css file and use them as a class:

```
.rtl{direction:rtl!important;}
.ltr{direction:ltr!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, it is worth adding that simply using rtl bootstrap library it is not always enough. In cases it is necessary to use symbols such as &, !, @, $, etc. they will appear on the right side of the sentence, even though the sentences in Arabic or Hebrew are written from right to left.
If you want them to appear at the end of the sentence, (which is the leftmost side of the sentence in Arabic, Hebrew and the like), you must add
`<html dir="rtl">`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-right` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<p dir="rtl" class="text-right">
حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ أَمْرُنَا وَفَارَ التَّنُّورُ قُلْنَا احْمِلْ فِيهَا مِنْ كُلٍّ زَوْجَيْنِ اثْنَيْنِ وَأَهْلَكَ إِلَّا مَنْ سَبَقَ عَلَيْهِ الْقَوْلُ وَمَنْ آَمَنَ وَمَا آَمَنَ مَعَهُ إِلَّا قَلِيلٌ  <span class="ayat_period">٣</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps could be helpful if someone is adding the RTL support to existing project created using Bootstrap 4 and SASS:

1. Add `dir="rtl"` and `lang="ar"` ('ar' is for arabic) to your HTML (Javascript: `document.documentElement.dir = "rtl"`)
2. Replace the possible properties with the help of [Mozilla RTL Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/RTL_Guidelines).
3. Import sass files from [bootstrap4-rtl](https://github.com/alipajand/bootstrap4-rtl) which converts bootstrap classes for RTL.
4. Next, change remaining styles by adding extra CSS: `[dir="rtl"] .class-name { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

Simply add ("text-right") class to the element you want to have it RTL along with the `<html dir="rtl">`.

Once your document loads, you run this check and apply the RTL class (text-right), but it will apply to all the web page div elements, enjoy bro and Jazakallah khairan :)

```
window.onload = function () {
if (document.documentElement.lang == 'ar') {
    var docDivz = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (let i = 0; i < docDivz.length; i++) {
      if (docDivz[i].classList.contains("text-center")) {
        continue;
      }
      docDivz[i].classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
}
```

You can do the same for "section" and/or "button" or whatever you want to be RTL.

Comment: Hi, though your answer may look like to make RTL work with bootstrap, it does not. It just hacks it. `text-right` in bootstrap is a class used to add `text-align: right` CSS property to an element. It does not contribute to the directionality of content inside. It is especially visible when RTL and LTR context are used in combination (like text and number). There are many projects aiming towards that like one from [rtlcss](https://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I understand that text-right is for alignment and it should be along with <html dir="rtl"> but it is very helpful in projects where you have RTL and LTR in the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Try below solution. It has worked for me. I hope it helps you.

```
 <p class="yourClass" dir="rtl">
      <p>Your elements should be here</p>   
 </p>
```

---

Comment: Similar solution has already been mentioned in some of the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*